# Are Azure services IP-addresses static

Tags: azure, firewall, azure-cognitive-services

I have access to a server behind a corporate firewall. I need a web application on it to talk with https://westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v1.0/ocr. The infrastructure department want an IP number to that service, so they can open up a hole in the corporate firewall, so the application is allowed to make the out-going call. If I do an 'nslookup westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com' I can see the receiving IP is 13.93.122.1 - but will it always be so... Is there a range I should know, or can I be certain that the Microsoft IP remains static?

Comment: Your infrastructure department is living in a bubble in the past. There is zero guarantee that a public facing API will sit on the same IP address for any period of time. This is true for every public cloud out there and is an artifact of scale and availability. There's this PowerShell module that - to some extent - could be used to allow the entier Azure West Europe region outbound - https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzurePublicIPAddresses/0.8.3

Comment: @evilSnobu Thanks, helpful. Agree with your comments and will argue (slightly rephrased) as much with said department.